# remap tablespace values on a create index ddl stored in a table column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

We have stored the create index ddl on a oracle table (under clob column), while try to create it we might need to remap different tablespace name for different partitions like tablespace [E01-E32] -> [I_CDDV1-32], example E01 -> I_CDDV1, E02 -> I_CDDV2 ... E32 -> I_CDDV32, below is the sample ddl info stored in the clob column of the oracle table. kindly advice. Thanks !

```
  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "TESTDBA"."AKTEST_IDX" ON "TESTDBA"."TEST_IDX_" ("TEST_ID1", "TEST_ID2",
"TEST_ID3")
  PCTFREE 1 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255  NOLOGGING
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACH
E DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "I01"  LOCAL
 (PARTITION "TEST_IDX01"  COMPRESS
  TABLESPACE "E01" ,
 PARTITION "TEST_IDX02"  COMPRESS
  TABLESPACE "E02" ,
 PARTITION "TEST_IDX03"  COMPRESS
  TABLESPACE "E03" ,
 PARTITION "TEST_IDX04"  COMPRESS
  TABLESPACE "E04" ,
 PARTITION "TEST_IDX05"  COMPRESS
  TABLESPACE "E05" ,
 PARTITION "TEST_IDX06"  COMPRESS
  TABLESPACE "E06" ,
 PARTITION "TEST_IDX07"  COMPRESS
  TABLESPACE "E07" ,
 PARTITION "TEST_IDX08"  COMPRESS
  TABLESPACE "E08" ,
 PARTITION "TEST_IDX09"  COMPRESS
  TABLESPACE "E09" ,
 PARTITION "TEST_IDX10"  COMPRESS
  TABLESPACE "E10" ,
 PARTITION "TEST_IDX11"  COMPRESS
  TABLESPACE "E11" ,
 PARTITION "TEST_IDX12"  COMPRESS
  TABLESPACE "E12" ,
 PARTITION "TEST_IDX13"  COMPRESS
  TABLESPACE "E13" ,
 PARTITION "TEST_IDX14"  COMPRESS
  TABLESPACE "E14" ,
 PARTITION "TEST_IDX15"  COMPRESS
  TABLESPACE "E15" ,
 PARTITION "TEST_IDX16"  COMPRESS
  TABLESPACE "E16" ,
 PARTITION "TEST_IDX17"  COMPRESS
  TABLESPACE "E17" ,
 PARTITION "TEST_IDX18"  COMPRESS
  TABLESPACE "E18" ,
 PARTITION "TEST_IDX19"  COMPRESS
  TABLESPACE "E19" ,
 PARTITION "TEST_IDX20"  COMPRESS
  TABLESPACE "E20" ,
 PARTITION "TEST_IDX21"  COMPRESS
  TABLESPACE "E21" ,
 PARTITION "TEST_IDX22"  COMPRESS
  TABLESPACE "E22" ,
 PARTITION "TEST_IDX23"  COMPRESS
  TABLESPACE "E23" ,
 PARTITION "TEST_IDX24"  COMPRESS
  TABLESPACE "E24" ,
 PARTITION "TEST_IDX25"  COMPRESS
  TABLESPACE "E25" ,
 PARTITION "TEST_IDX26"  COMPRESS
  TABLESPACE "E26" ,
 PARTITION "TEST_IDX27"  COMPRESS
  TABLESPACE "E27" ,
 PARTITION "TEST_IDX28"  COMPRESS
  TABLESPACE "E28" ,
 PARTITION "TEST_IDX29"  COMPRESS
  TABLESPACE "E29" ,
 PARTITION "TEST_IDX30"  COMPRESS
  TABLESPACE "E30" ,
 PARTITION "TEST_IDX31"  COMPRESS
  TABLESPACE "E31" ,
 PARTITION "TEST_IDX32"  COMPRESS
  TABLESPACE "E32" ) COMPRESS 2;
```

Comment: Search & replace in your favorite text editor?

Comment: yeah, if its a 1 or few indexes we can do that, but multiple indexes under multiple tables. thats why need some inputs around that.

Comment: btw, tablespace name are standard across all indexes

Comment: Were those DDLs generated from some physical database or they were generated by other software/hand coded? In the former case you may opt to store it as a CLOB or XMLType and use `dbms_metadata` package to transform a DDL in a managed way (not with string parsing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need a Replace procedure for CLOB.
Hopefully this could be usefull. Regards...

```sql
Create Or Replace PROCEDURE 
    CLOB_REPLACE    (
                        pClob IN OUT CLOB,
                        pStr IN VarChar2,
                        pReplace IN VarChar2 
                    ) 
AS
BEGIN
    Declare
        Pos Number;
    Begin
        Pos := DBMS_LOB.InStr(pClob, pStr);
        --
        If Nvl(Pos, 0) > 0 Then
            DBMS_LOB.Copy( pClob, pClob, DBMS_LOB.GetLength(pClob), Pos + Length(pReplace), Pos + Length(pStr) );
            DBMS_LOB.Write( pClob, Length(pReplace), Pos, pReplace );
            
            If Length(pStr) > Length(pReplace) Then
                DBMS_LOB.Trim(pClob, DBMS_LOB.GetLength(pClob) - (Length(pStr) - Length(pReplace)));
            End If;
        End If;
        --
    End;
END CLOB_REPLACE;
--
--  T e s t
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
Declare
    mClob CLOB;
Begin
    mClob := 'Replace part of CLOB (this part) with something else';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(mClob);
    CLOB_REPLACE( mClob, 'this part', 'this part replaced' );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(mClob);
End;
--  
--  T e s t    R e s u l t
--  
--  anonymous block completed
--  Replace part of CLOB (this part) with something else.
--  Replace part of CLOB (this part replaced) with something else.
```